# Using jQuery to show/hide html content only works if class is hard-coded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of hidden html form-groups that I want to display based on the values chosen in two cascading select lists. I'm using jQuery to toggle a class on the second list which is then called by an on change event function.

If I hard-code the class, the subsequent form-groups are shown when the on change is fired.

If I use the toggleClass from jQuery to dynamically change the class, the on change function doesn't fire even though the class is toggled correctly.

### HTML

```
          <div class="form-group hidden" id="option_env">
                <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label" for="ddl_env">Options</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                    <select name="category" id="ddl_env" class="form-control ">
                        <option value="-- Select an option --">-- Select an option --</option>
                        <option value="horse">Tethered horses</option>
                        <option value="Watercourses">Watercourses</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
          </div>
```

### jQuery

```
var cascadeSelect = $('#ddlcategory');    

var optionSelect =  cascadeSelect.on('change', function () {
    hideAll();

    var option = $(this).val();
    var childSelect = showOption(option);
    return childSelect;
});

$('.option').on('change', function () {
    hideDetail();

    var detail = $(this).val();
    showDetail(detail);        
});

function showOption(option) {   
    var returnOption = null;
    $('#' + option).toggleClass('chosen hidden')
        .find('select').toggleClass('option')
        ;

    var ddl_option = option.substr(option.indexOf('_')+1);
    return returnOption = $('#ddl_' + ddl_option);
}
```

This works insofar as the `ddl_env` select has the `option` class added by the jQuery `find`, however, the  `$('.option').on('change', function ()` doesn't fire when the select list item is changed.

If I comment out the line `.find('select').toggleClass('option')` and manually add the `option` class to the `ddl_env` select then it works fine.

I get the same result with jQuery.addClass.

Debugging in Chrome shows that the `ddl_env` select change doesn't fire the change event when the `option` class isn't hard-coded.

Comment: You don't have an element with the class `option`, adding that class later doesn't matter, the event handler is only bound to elements matching the selector at pageload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic question.
Replace

```
$('.option').on('change', function()...
```

with

```
$(document).on('change', '.option', function()...
```

The second syntax works on present and future '.option' items.

Answer (score 3):

This handler will only work on anything with the clas `option` when the page loads

```
$('.option').on('change', function () {
    hideDetail();

    var detail = $(this).val();
    showDetail(detail);        
});
```

In order for you to get it to work on elements dynamically allocated that class after the page has loadewd you need to delegate the event handler to a higher element, so basically its parent, or if all else fails `document`

```
$(document).on('change', '.option', function () {
    hideDetail();

    var detail = $(this).val();
    showDetail(detail);        
});
```